# If a PE file has x86 code in it, is it considered a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I understand that a .exe PE file can have [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) code in it. But if it has x86 code in it, is it considered a .NET assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A .NET executable will have another PE header ([`IMAGE_COR20_HEADER`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetformat.aspx)), in addition to the normal headers, which describes the executable as a .NET assembly. The native code found in there will import `mscoree.dll` and, in the case of executables, jump to [`_CorExeMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh0859k0.aspx) to complete the loading of your assembly.

If the assembly contains only managed code, the `COMIMAGE_FLAGS_ILONLY` flag will be set in the header.

Comment: As I understand your answer, the `IMAGE_COR20_HEADER` is the literal definition of a .NET assembly. Whether or not the file has x86 code is not relevant to that fact. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

A .NET assembly can contain IL as well as machine code.  These are called 'mixed-mode' assemblies, the C++/CLI compiler can generate them. Several .NET assemblies are mixed-mode assemblies, System.Data.dll and PresentationCore.dll are good examples.  One give-away is the presence of a non-empty `<Module>` class in the global namespace.  It may have a static constructor (.cctor) that starts up the C Runtime support that's needed for native code.  Another hint is from the corflags.exe utility, they'll have ILONLY = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you may or may not call it that, depending on where it came from.

A **.NET assembly** is any library that contains .NET metadata and requires a CLR to execute. A **mixed-mode assembly**, for example, contains both managed and unmanaged code.

It's possible to get a completely unmanaged assembly if you take a managed assembly and run `ngen` on it. This gives you a "pre-JITted" assembly. However, Microsoft's parlance for this situation would be to call the original IL version as **managed assembly**, and the post-JIT version a **native image of the managed assembly**.

Note that as far as .NET is concerned, the only difference between an "exe" and a "dll" is that one has a static Main method entry point that the CLR can jump to and one does not. Both are "assemblies" with the same basic internal structure. So the same terms apply.

Answer (score -1):

All `.exe`s in this context have x86 code in them, else you wouldn't be able to start them.  Since all .exes have x86 code, and not all .exes are .NET assemblies, the answer is no.

I suspect you mean if they have *unmanaged* code though?  In which case..

You can do it, but only by having the unmanaged code as an embedded resource AFAIK: http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx

You can't create a .NET assembly with unmanaged code 'just' in it: how would it compile?  What would the entry point be?  To call unmanaged code, you must declare a `DllImport` which needs a .dll name - you can't refer to your own assembly.

Comment: I don't meant to hijack the question, but what about mixed-mode assemblies or managed C++?

Comment: @Kragen: they'll still have to bootstrap `mscoree.dll` to get the framework going. As for if they have the .Net PE headers, that I don't know.

Comment: @Kragen - great point, I may be technically/completely wrong.  Hopefully someone can advise.